# UITextView done button action - on return key

Tags: ios

Using UITextView, how do you know when "Done" or other is pressed on the keyboard?

Do I need to look at every char in `textViewDidChange` and if so, what to look for?

IB selected UITextView:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tested this.  Seems to satisfy your requirement:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       myTextView.delegate = self
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
    {
        if(text == "\n")
        {
            view.endEditing(true)
            return false
        }
        else
        {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter in the sense that if you have specified you are the Delegate for the call you are going to get that call.  Can be Done, Go, Next, whatever it is you select in Interface Builder or you set programmatically.

Comment: @ChrisG. Did you set the Delegate?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do that in `textViewDidChange` by looking for a newline `"\n"`.

Otherwise, a better idea would be to use `func textView(UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn: NSRange, replacementText: String)` by checking `replacementText == "\n"`

Example:

```
func textView(UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn: NSRange, replacementText: String){
    if replacementText == "\n"{
        // do your stuff here
        // return false here, if you want to disable user from adding newline
    }
    // otherwise, it will return true and the text will be replaced
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that will be bouth for enter and ok button. I need the user to be able to add new lines. Also it is "\n" :-)

Comment: Which ok button? Do you mean the 'Done' button?
AFAIK, that produces "\n" in UITextView.

Comment: Yes, my answer would be the same. The return key produces "\n". Whether you allow user to add new lines, depend on what you return on the `func textView(UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn: NSRange, replacementText: String)`